# What is difference between rmagick and imagemagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

DO I need to install rmagick to install imagemagick on windows platform ? How they relate to each other ? Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, i think you have it the opposite way around, you need to install imagemagick first, to install rmagick.

Rmagic is the Ruby extension for using imagemagick within Ruby. Imagemagick on the other hand, is the actual 'program'.

You should check out this guide: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html

> First you have to install ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick, and those
>   libraries require a lot of other libraries.

Comment: And I have heard of devkit required to install.Could you tell about this ?.

Comment: I haven't used Devkit before, but from looking at the docs on both, rmagick and devkit, i THINK dev kit is just a compiler and you don't need to use it win the  rmagick-win32 gem http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#gcc

Answer (score 2):

[`rmagick`](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) is Ruby library/wrapper which allows to use ImageMagick image manipulation routines.

If you simply want ImageMagick and its command-line utilities like `convert`, `mogrify`, etc, then you certainly do not need `rmagick` - just install [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org).

If you want to manipulate images from Ruby or Ruby on Rails, then you need both.

Answer (score 2):

rmagick is the Ruby gem that allows you to interact with the ImageMagick library (which is binary code and can be run from the command line)

So you need rmagick only if you want to use ImageMagick from Ruby code. (and ImageMagick must be installed)

Using rmagick would not be mandatory, but if you don't want to use it, you would have to code all the calls to the command line tools yourself.